# Prove "If $\{R, Q\} \vDash P$, then $¬P \vdash \lnot Q \lor \lnot R$".

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Using the book Dirk van Dalen. "*Logic and Structure (Universitext)*" as reference text.

*Decide whether the following statement is true or false, justifying the answer.*

> If $\{R, Q\} \vDash P$, then $¬P \vdash \lnot Q \lor \lnot R$.

I claim this statement is true.

**Proof:**

Assume $[[R]]_v=[[Q]]_v=1 \Rightarrow [[P]]_v=1$.

Let *v* an arbitrary valuation.

By completeness theorem,

> $¬P \vDash \lnot Q \lor \lnot R \Rightarrow ¬P \vdash \lnot Q \lor \lnot R$

So, we can now try to prove $¬P \vDash \lnot Q \lor \lnot R$.

Assume $[[\lnot P]]_v=1$ (*).

- Assume $\lnot ([[\lnot Q \lor \lnot R]]_v = 1)$

  - Assume $[[R]]_v=[[Q]]_v=1$
  - $[[P]]_v=1$
  - $[[P]]_v=0$ (From (*))
  - $\bot$
- $\lnot([[R]]_v=[[Q]]_v=1)$
- $[[\lnot Q]]_v=1 \lor [[\lnot R]]_v=1$
- $[[\lnot Q \lor \lnot R]]_v = 1$
- $\bot$

$[[\lnot Q \lor \lnot R]]_v = 1$

$[[¬P]]_v=1 \Rightarrow [[\lnot Q \lor \lnot R]]_v=1$

$¬P \vDash \lnot Q \lor \lnot R$

I will appreciate if someone could give some insight into the general structure of the proof and I would like to know whether my attempt is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic proof plan is correct ... but it is a little werd to use propositional logic notation for a meta-proof.

For example, you say things like

> $\lnot([[R]]_v=[[Q]]_v=1)$

and

> $[[\lnot Q ]]_v =1 \lor [[\lnot R]]_v = 1$

so now you are using propositional logic operators to make your meta-logical claims, which is very confusing.

So, I would suggest to just stick with English, just as you would with any mathematical proof, and instead say:

> it is not the case that both $[[R]]_v =1$ and $[[Q]]_v =1$

and

> either $[[\neg Q]]_v =1$ or $[[\neg R]]_v =1$

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable insight ! Could you give me some advice about how to indent or format this type of proof? I feel some things are not very clear. Should I avoid indentation altogether ?

Comment: I see now I mistyped the statement. I should have used \vdash instead of \vDash in the consequent. Is my proof still valid ? Could I do it without using completeness theorem ?

Comment: @F.Zer Actually, that's the other thing. Just like you made your meta-logical claims to look like logic expressions, you also made your meta-logical proof very much in the style of a formal logic proof. Now, of course the *very idea* of a formal proof is that it provides you with a rigorous proof structure, and that this proof structure reflects how you would do a mathematical proof. Still, I think here too you could do a few things to make your meta-logical proof feel a little less like a formal proof. Once again, throw in some words and phrases like: 'this means that', 'we now see that' etc.

Comment: @F.Zer I don;t understand what you meant by your mistyping ... I think your proof plan was just fine. Yes, first show that If $\{R, Q\} \vDash P$, then $¬P \vDash \lnot Q \lor \lnot R$, and then use the Completeness Theorem to get $¬P \vdash \lnot Q \lor \lnot R$. And yes, you'll need to know *something* about your proof system in order to make any claims regarding $\vdash$. Completeness may not be required for this particular problem, but it sure makes it easy! And, I bet that the book simply assumes Completeness all along.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insights, @Bram28 ! Regarding mistyping, originally the title said: If $\{R, Q\} \vDash P$, then $¬P \vDash \lnot Q \lor \lnot R$ instead of If $\{R, Q\} \vDash P$, then $¬P \vdash \lnot Q \lor \lnot R$

Comment: Oh!  OK, so then you don't need Completeness at all.

Comment: Not sure I clarified this issue, @Bram28. Haha. My original post title was wrong, I should have said. The correct one is: If $\{R, Q\} \vDash P$, then $¬P \vdash \lnot Q \lor \lnot R$. So, I need Completeness, as you said.

Comment: @F.Zer Oh!  Now I get it :P  So yes, back to Completeness :)